# Solr : IOException occured when talking to Server

Tags: solr

I have been struggling to find a solution to this problem which I have tried to explain here. Would really appreciate some ideas that I could try, to fix this.

We have Spring Web Services with Microsoft SQL Server as back end. We have been working on SQL to SOLR migration project, where we are required to index all the SQL data to SOLR and perform searches there instead, due to a lot of performance issues our application has been facing.

The basic approach that we took is as follows:

1) Created SOLR EAR as mentioned HERE

2) Deployed the SOLR EAR on IBM Websphere v7.0 in the DEV env

3) Deployed the Spring Web Services EAR on Websphere server in LOCAL

4) Following is how we are trying to access the core from web service. Here, I have shown example of one core whereas in the actual code, we are accessing multiple cores in the same way.

spring.xml

:/solr/collection1/"/>

SearchEngineRepositoryImpl.java

```
package com.example.solr.repository;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.data.geo.Circle;
import org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.solr.core.query.Criteria;
import org.springframework.data.solr.core.query.FacetOptions;
import org.springframework.data.solr.core.query.SimpleFacetQuery;
import org.springframework.data.solr.core.query.SimpleQuery;
import org.springframework.data.solr.core.query.result.FacetEntry;
import org.springframework.data.solr.core.query.result.FacetPage;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class SearchEngineRepositoryImpl implements SearchEngineRepository{

  @Resource
  private SolrTemplate solrTemplateCollection1;

  public List<SearchDocument> search(SearchCriteria searchCriteria){

    Criteria solrSearchCriteira  = new Criteria("name").contains(searchCriteria.getName());

    SimpleFacetQuery searchQuery = new SimpleFacetQuery(solrSearchCriteira);

    FacetPage<SearchDocument> results =  solrTemplateCollection1.queryForFacetPage(searchQuery,SearchDocument.class);

    // rest of code
    .
    .
    .
  }
}
```

When I am trying to run the web service, I am getting the following exception:

```
UUID: 4b5f05b1-23ce-4b80-b6cb-bfef6d1e5abd Cause: org.springframework.data.solr.UncategorizedSolrException: IOException occured when talking to server at: http://<host>:<port>/solr/collection1; nested exception is org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: IOException occured when talking to server at: http://<host>:<port>/solr/collection1
    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.execute(SolrTemplate.java:122)
    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.query(SolrTemplate.java:332)
    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.queryForFacetPage(SolrTemplate.java:286)
    at com.example.solr.repository.SearchEngineRepositoryImpl.search(SearchEngineRepositoryImpl.java:105)
    at com.example.solr.service.SearchServiceImpl.search(SearchServiceImpl.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.MethodEndpoint.invoke(MethodEndpoint.java:134)
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter.invokeInternal(DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter.java:240)
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.AbstractMethodEndpointAdapter.invoke(AbstractMethodEndpointAdapter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.dispatch(MessageDispatcher.java:233)
    at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.receive(MessageDispatcher.java:173)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:88)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:59)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.doService(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:292)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:960)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1064)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:909)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:283)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)

Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: IOException occured when talking to server at: http://<host>:<port>/solr/collection1
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:413)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:180)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.QueryRequest.process(QueryRequest.java:90)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.query(SolrServer.java:301)
    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate$11.doInSolr(SolrTemplate.java:339)
    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate$11.doInSolr(SolrTemplate.java:336)
    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.execute(SolrTemplate.java:118)
    ... 53 more

Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to host:port timed out
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:129)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:640)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:784)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:352)
    ... 59 more
```

I am able to invoke SOLR console and other SOLR queries in the browser.

Also, when I deploy the Web Services and SOLR EARs on the same Websphere server (i.e. after changing the hostname to localhost in the spring.xml), I am getting a proper response.

There is no authentication setup in the web.xml of SOLR EAR.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5"
         metadata-complete="true"
>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>SolrRequestFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SolrRequestFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>


  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Zookeeper</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.solr.servlet.ZookeeperInfoServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>LoadAdminUI</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.solr.servlet.LoadAdminUiServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>RedirectOldAdminUI</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.solr.servlet.RedirectServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>destination</param-name>
      <param-value>${context}/#/</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>RedirectOldZookeeper</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.solr.servlet.RedirectServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>destination</param-name>
      <param-value>${context}/zookeeper</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>RedirectLogging</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.solr.servlet.RedirectServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>destination</param-name>
      <param-value>${context}/#/~logging</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>SolrRestApi</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>org.restlet.application</param-name>
      <param-value>org.apache.solr.rest.SolrRestApi</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RedirectOldAdminUI</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/admin/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RedirectOldAdminUI</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/admin</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RedirectOldZookeeper</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/zookeeper.jsp</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RedirectLogging</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/logging</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Zookeeper</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/zookeeper</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoadAdminUI</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/admin.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SolrRestApi</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/schema/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>.xsl</extension>
    <mime-type>application/xslt+xml</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>admin.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Providing other info on SOLR setup for reference:

SOLR Home location :: /Websphere/AppServer/profiles/AppServer01/solr

SOLR Core location :: /Websphere/AppServer/profiles/AppServer01/solr/collection1

solr.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<solr persistent="false">

  <cores adminPath="/admin/cores" host="${host:}" hostPort="${jetty.port:8983}" hostContext="${hostContext:solr}" defaultCoreName="collection1">
    <core name="collection1" instanceDir="collection1" />

    <shardHandlerFactory name="shardHandlerFactory" class="HttpShardHandlerFactory">
      <str name="urlScheme">${urlScheme:}</str>
    </shardHandlerFactory>
  </cores>

</solr>
```